# Python regex for string parse

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn regex for python and try to get token and session values in the string. I get as in the below but is there a better way from here to get token and session values?
here is my code also string:

```
    a ={}
    import re
    b ="token: d9706bc7-c599-4c99-b55e-bc49cba4bc0d\nsession:NjA5MWE2MGQtMTgxNS00NWY5LTkwYWQtM2Q0MWE3OTFlNTY0\n"
    a=re.findall("([A-Za-z]+[\d@]+[\w@]*|[\d@]+[A-Za-z]+[\w@])",b)

    print(a[5]) #this is for session value "NjA5MWE2MGQtMTgxNS00NWY5LTkwYWQtM2Q0MWE3OTFlNTY0"
    print ([a[0:5]]) #this is for getting token as array d9706bc7 c599 4c99 b55e bc49cba4bc0d

How can I get the token value with - as in the below:
"d9706bc7-c599-4c99-b55e-bc49cba4bc0d"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a very simple regexp to get it:

```
a=re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9-]+", b)
print(a[1]) # Outputs d9706bc7-c599-4c99-b55e-bc49cba4bc0d
```

Even shorter, will give you same result:

```
a=re.findall("[\w-]+", b)
print(a[1]) # Outputs d9706bc7-c599-4c99-b55e-bc49cba4bc0d
```

Comment: thank you :) @dmitryro so I have to write a new regex to take session value? is there any  shorter way to get token and session values ?